Error "Capability not supported" trying to create BDE.TTable with ADT field in Delphi 11
I receive the error "capability not supported" when I try to create a BDE TTable that has a ADT field.
Does not BDE support ADT fields?
The code to reproduce the problem follows
form declaration
    object Form14: TForm14
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Form14'
      ClientHeight = 442
      ClientWidth = 628
      Color = clBtnFace
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWindowText
      Font.Height = -12
      Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
      Font.Style = []
      OnCreate = FormCreate
      TextHeight = 15
      object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
        Left = 0
        Top = 128
        Width = 628
        Height = 314
        Align = alBottom
        DataSource = DataSource1
        TabOrder = 0
        TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
        TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
        TitleFont.Height = -12
        TitleFont.Name = 'Segoe UI'
        TitleFont.Style = []
      end
      object DataSource1: TDataSource
        DataSet = Table1
        Left = 120
        Top = 168
      end
      object Table1: TTable
        FieldDefs = <
          item
            Name = 'Address'
            ChildDefs = <
              item
                Name = 'City'
                DataType = ftString
                Size = 20
              end
              item
                Name = 'Road'
                DataType = ftString
                Size = 20
              end
              item
                Name = 'Number'
                DataType = ftString
                Size = 5
              end>
            DataType = ftADT
            Size = 3
          end>
        StoreDefs = True
        Left = 128
        Top = 72
      end
    end```


unit Unit141;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Bde.DBTables, Vcl.Grids,     Vcl.DBGrids;

type
  TForm14 = class(TForm)
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    Table1: TTable;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form14: TForm14;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm14.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if not Table1.Exists
    then Table1.CreateTable;
    Table1.Open;
end;

end.


PS. I try with `ObjectView` TRUE and FALSE 


Why in the world are you still using the BDE? It has been deprecated for nearly two decades, and non-supported for at least one. I'm surprised you can still compile code for it any longer. You've had plenty of time to move into this century by now - it's 2024, not 1994. You should probably explain what an ADT field is - some of the people here weren't born when the BDE died out and may not know.

@KenWhite. I use BDE because it is a free local database that can work on a network using the server only as a file server which is very important to me. ADT field is a field with sub-fields (like a record)

There are many free local databases that aren't ancient, require you to use antique technologies, and don't require installation of the BDE to work. They also support modern functionality and require far less maintenance. There's a reason the BDE was dropped ages ago - it was a bad DBMS then, and it's even worse now. Do you still use Windows 3.1 on an 80386?

I only know Absolute Database as an BDE alternative (I use it in another app) but does not support ADT fields. All other alternatives are of client-server type that isn't suitable for me because I haven't local access to server. I need a local database engine which accesses local or remote files. Could you suggest me such a replacement?

You don't need ADT fields. Use another table, and link them on a common field. It looks like you're really stuck on 1990s methodology. You should find a good book or tutorial on databases and SQL. There are many databases that you can use the way you describe. You can ask for suggestions for specific ones on [softwarerecs.se].

@JimPapas have you ever heard of SQLite or embedded DBMS. Be aware that SQLite is not designed for a multiuser environment like e.g. MySQL or SQL Server!

This Q is so sloppily formatted and you didn't notice it so many times. SQLite is so easy to use when you can finally let go of DB related components. It's really not black magic.
